# NSUserDefaults crashes when adding empty array

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsuserdefaults, iphone-5

I just moved to iOS 8, installed Xcode 6 etc. 
This code worked nicely on iOS 7 and 6. It even seems to work on an iPhone 4S with iOS 8 installed. But on iPhones 5 and 5S it crashes. (8.0.0 and 8.0.2 alike) 
It does not matter whether the app is build against SDK 7 or 8. It crashes in both cases at the same stage.

The .h file contains:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* filterBrandsExclude;
```

from the .m file:

```
// Following lines just to set the conditions for your understanding: 
    _filterBrandsExclude = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0]; // just creates an empty array. 
// As a matter of fact, this array may well be empty and it worked nicely on older iOS versions. 

// this line crashes: 
    [userDefaults setObject:_filterBrandsExclude forKey:@"filterBrandsExclude"];
```

Error Message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyValueSlowMutableArray getObjects:range:]: value for key filterBrandsExclude of object 0x17004ae00 is nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1885c6084 0x198bac0e4 0x1885c5fc4 0x18946097c 0x189460a68 0x189460ab0 0x1884c24d0 0x18854be90 0x1884c21c0 0x1884c17e8 0x188627c80 0x188552d9c 0x188551e9c 0x188600290 0x1885ff840 0x1886030e4 0x1893bb750 0x100053e5c 0x1000522a4 0x18cfd65d4 0x18cfdead0 0x18cfdea58 0x18cfd238c 0x1907d1640 0x18857e360 0x18857d468 0x18857ba8c 0x1884a9664 0x1915eb5a4 0x18cdae984 0x1000515f4 0x19921aa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. In your error it says that the value for the key `filterBrandsInclude` is nil, but in your question you reference the key `filterBrandsExclude`. Are you sure you've pinpointed the actual error at this point?

EDIT: Point #2 is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for point 1. It is a copy&past error. I'll fix my question. 
Yes, storing NSNull or removing the value with this key from the preferences could be a workaround.

Comment: Well, just to let you know, adding `[NSNull null]` instead results in `Attempt to set a non-property-list object null as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key filterBrandsExclude` and the same happens when I add `[NSNull null]` as dummy entry to the array.

Comment: `NSNull` is not a property list object and user defaults can only store property list objects (`NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`). Also collections (arrays/dicts) may only contain property list objects as well. That's because user defaults are not written using `NSCoding` (it's not object serialization).

Answer (score 0):

you can manually check

```
if(self.filterBrandsExclude != nil && self.filterBrandsExclude.count > 0)
    [userDefaults  setObject:_filterBrandsExclude forKey:@"filterBrandsExclude"];
else
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"filterBrandsExclude"];
```

Comment: That is certainly the workaround that I will go for. But it does not explain the issue itself.

Comment: reason is nil value cannot be stored in NSDefaults